# JSF calling viewparams for every AJAX request

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF page that accepts a viewparam and sets a variable which looks up the respective entity from the database and load the bean with the found details as follows:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="attractionId" value="#{attractionsBean.attractionId}" />
</f:metadata>
```

I have a google map using the primefaces API and when a marker is dragged, an ajax call is issued to update the marker location.

```
<h:outputText value="Location" />
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <p:gmap id="gmap" center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="10" type="HYBRID" style="width:380px;height:350px"
                        model="#{attractionsBean.attractionModel.mapModel}"
                        markerDragListener="#{attractionsBean.onMarkerDrag}"
                        onMarkerDragUpdate="growl" />
                </f:view>
```

The problem is that after every marker drag event and ajax call, the method setAttractionId from the metadata is called every time.

What can be a solution for this problem to prevent calling the setAttractionId method everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem is as follows after a lot of hours trying to find a workaround:

1. Make the ManagedBean as `@ViewScoped` in order to be the same bean while still on the same page
2. Instead of retrieving the entity from the database in the setter of the attractionId, I introduced a `@PostConstruct` method in the view scoped bean to retrieve the object by the view parameter using the code as follows:

   ```
   @PostConstruct
   public void setupAttractionModel() {
       this.attractionId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(ATTRACTION_ID_VIEW_PARAM);
       // Lookup by attractionId ...
   }
   ```

   The postconstruct method is called before every page that requires the bean.
3. Remove the `<f:metadata>` tag which is causing the trouble

Comment: This will work but I would like to ad that managed properties DO work with ViewScoped beans, I use them all the time in my Primefaces application.  The trick is that I keep references to my domain model entities in the managed bean instance, and I only fetch them from the database if those references are null or when explicitly called for.  Doing it this way, I can perform a number of manipulations to entities within the scope of my view, and not actually submit the database changes until explicitly called for.  The references get cleaned up after the lifecycle of the managed bean has ended.

Comment: @maple_shaft sorry my mistake then r.e. the managed property .. but i had a problem injecting a string value but at least it worked .. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Really the better way is to keep the setter as a simple setter and use a delayed instantiation pattern:

1. Set an instance variable of the id in setAttractionId if dirty and clear the current retrieved instance. If the variable is not dirty the attraction instance will remain unmodified.
2. In the getter (getAttractionModel) retrieve the attraction instance if null using the attraction id. Subsequent calls to the getter will return the instance without retrieving from db.
3. Remove the post construct

This will work with a ViewScoped bean.

Answer (score 0):

The setter in your managed bean might be request scoped.  Try setting the managed bean to ViewScoped and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: The managed bean was actually a session bean in order to prevent this .. which is a wider scope than ViewScoped

Comment: Well this makes sense then.  Why is this a problem that this being called every time?

Comment: The problem is that in the setter of the ID, I am retrieving the respective entity from the DB.  If this is called everytime, it will be refreshed with every call.  I have discovered a workaround and posted it as an answer :)  Thanks anyways